# terminal command to act on filenames that don't contain text

Tags: unix, terminal, cp

I have a directory full of files with names such as:

```
file_name_is_001
file_name_001
file_name_is_002
file_name_002
file_name_is_003
file_name_003
```

I want to copy only the files that don't contain 'is'. I'm not sure how to do this. I have tried to search for it, but can't seem to google the right phrase to find the results.

Answer (score 2):

Details depend on operating system, shell, etc.
For a unix system a quite verbose but easy to understand approach could look like this (please mind that I didn't test it):

```
mkdir some_temporary_directory
mv *_is_* some_temporary_directory
cp * where_ever_you_want_to_copy_it
mv some_temporary_directory/* .
rmdir some_temporary_directory
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using `bash`.  First, here's a command to get you a list of files that don't contain the text `_is_`:

```
ls | grep -v "_is_"
```

This takes the output of `ls` and matches all values with DO NOT contain `_is_` using `grep -v`.

In order to then copy these files, we need to turn the lines output by grep into arguments of `cp`.  We can do this using `xargs`:

`ls | grep -v "_is_" | xargs -J % cp % new_folder`

From the `xargs` man page, it is a tool to "build and execute command lines from standard input".